# Inserting Previous Dates in R Vector

Tags: r, dataframe, data-cleaning

I'm trying to insert the previous date for every date in a vector in R.
This is my current vector:

```
[1] "1990-02-08" "1990-03-28" "1990-05-16" "1990-07-05" "1990-07-13" "1990-08-22" "1990-10-03"
[8] "1990-10-29" "1990-11-14" "1990-12-07" "1990-12-18" "1991-01-08" "1991-02-01" "1991-02-07"
```

I'm trying to get the following:

```
[1] "1990-02-07" "1990-02-08" "1990-03-27" "1990-03-28" "1990-05-15" "1990-05-16" "1990-07-05"
```

ect.

I tried the following:

```
dates_lagged = as.Date(dates)-1
dates_combined = c(date, dates_lagged)
```

However, with this method, some dates are not getting lagged.
Is there a better way to do this?

Edit: to answer the comment, this is my code (replaced CSV with its starting values):

```
FOMC <- read_csv(file = c("x", "1990-02-08", "1990-03-28", "1990-05-16", "1990-07-05", "1990-07-13", "1990-08-22", "1990-10-03",
                          "1990-10-29", "1990-11-14", "1990-12-07"))
FOMC$x <- as.Date(FOMC$x, format = "%Y-%m-%d")
colnames(FOMC) <- "Date"
dates_vector <- FOMC[["Date"]]
FOMC = as.vector(as.Date(dates_vector))
dates_lagged = as.Date(FOMC)-1
dates_combined = c(FOMC, dates_lagged)
as.Date(dates_combined)
```

For some reason, there is no "1990-10-28" before "1990-10-29" for example, and I can't figure out why.

Comment: Which dates are not getting lagged? Your solution seems to work for me.

Comment: @Matt I think the OP is looking for the final vector to be an interlaced version of `dates_lagged` and `dates`, so that the final vector effectively has the day before each date _inserted_ in the original vector. The current solution just appends the lagged dates at the end of the originals.

Comment: @Matt I added my code, and when I run it some dates are not getting lagged.

Comment: @AllanCameron good call! @Luca, you could also just do `sort(as.Date(dates_combined))`.

Comment: @Matt doh! That's the smart solution right there!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try:

```r
as.Date(c(rbind(dates - 1, dates)), origin = "1970-01-01")
#>  [1] "1990-02-07" "1990-02-08" "1990-03-27" "1990-03-28" "1990-05-15"
#>  [6] "1990-05-16" "1990-07-04" "1990-07-05" "1990-07-12" "1990-07-13"
#> [11] "1990-08-21" "1990-08-22" "1990-10-02" "1990-10-03" "1990-10-28"
#> [16] "1990-10-29" "1990-11-13" "1990-11-14" "1990-12-06" "1990-12-07"
#> [21] "1990-12-17" "1990-12-18" "1991-01-07" "1991-01-08" "1991-01-31"
#> [26] "1991-02-01" "1991-02-06" "1991-02-07"
```

---

**Data**

```r
dates <- c("1990-02-08", "1990-03-28", "1990-05-16", "1990-07-05", "1990-07-13", 
"1990-08-22", "1990-10-03", "1990-10-29", "1990-11-14", "1990-12-07", 
"1990-12-18", "1991-01-08", "1991-02-01", "1991-02-07")

dates <- as.Date(dates)
```

<sup>Created on 2021-11-04 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>

Comment: You may use `do.call(c, Map(c, dates-1, dates))` to avoid the conversion again

Comment: This code seems to work! I still don't understand what the issue with my solution is though...

Comment: @Luca your code just puts one vector at the end of the other vector, for example, if you had `a <- c(2, 4, 6)` and `b <- c(1, 3, 5)` then `c(b, a)` would give `1, 3, 5, 2, 4, 6`. So you are putting all your lagged dates at the end of the original dates, not inserting them in between the original dates.